# Select from a table where a condition is fulfilled and another is not

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 tables:

```
Students
(student_id, name, group, year, specialization)

Scolarships
(scolarship_id, name, description, duration)

Applicants
(student_id, scolarship_id)
```

I need to select all the students that have applied for scolarship with `id=2` and have not applied for scolarship with `id=4`

So far I have this query:

```
select students.name, students.group, students.specialization
from applicants ap
inner join students on students.id = ap.student_id
inner join scolarships on scolarships.scolarship_id = ap.scolarship_id
where ap.scolarship_id = 2;
```

This selects all the students that have applied for scolarship with id=2.

How can I add the condition that they have applied for scolarship 2 but haven't applied for scolarship 4?

Comment: Add one more condition, namely `AND NOT ap.scolarshop_id = 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists` something as

```
select students.name, students.group, students.specialization
from applicants ap
inner join students on students.id = ap.student_id
inner join scolarships on scolarships.scolarship_id = ap.scolarship_id
where 
ap.scolarship_id = 2
and not exists(
 select 1 from applicants ap1
 where 
 ap.student_id = ap1.student_id
 and ap1.scolarship_id = 4
)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select students.name, students.group, students.specialization
from applicants ap
inner join students on students.id = ap.student_id
inner join scolarships on scolarships.scolarship_id = ap.scolarship_id
where ap.scolarship_id = 2 and not exists(select * from applicants as t1
where t1.student_id = students.student_id and t1.scolarship_id = 4)
```